# Create a List of Users and their roles DataTable .Net Core 2.1 Razor Pages

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have a page I'm trying to display all the users and their assigned Roles.

I'm able to get My role, All roles, and All users.... but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the user and their role in the same query?

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
 {
    private readonly FishRoomDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(FishRoomDbContext application)
    {
        _context = application;
    }

    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; private set; }

    public List<IdentityUserRole<string>> UsersRoles { get; set; }  // get my roles or context of user

    public List<IdentityRole> AllRoles { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Users = _context.Users.ToList();
        UsersRoles = _context.UserRoles.ToList(); // get my roles or context 
        of user
        AllRoles = _context.Roles.ToList();
    }
}
```

How would I go about displaying that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class User{
//Foreign Key Reference
  public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
public class UserRole{
//Foreign Key Reference
 public int userID{get;set;} //ID field of user
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public partial class FishRoomDbContext : DbContext
{
 public FishRoomDbContext()
    : base("name=ConnectionStringName")
 {
   this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
 }
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
            .WithRequired(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.userID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 }
```

**Your Method**

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        Users = _context.Users.Include("UserRoles").ToList();
        UsersRoles = _context.UserRoles.ToList(); // get my roles or context 
        of user
        AllRoles = _context.Roles.ToList();
    }
```

What i did is , i added foreign key reference, do it in your dbms too. Now when you will call your method `OnGet()` all the users will be fetched with their roles. Roles willl be in `User.UserRoles` property.