# Linq query to explicitly load related data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core to work against a pre-existing database. It's a pretty common model that uses a lot of join tables, specific to my case, a join table for `users` to `roles`. The `UserRole` table has just two columns - a `UserId` and a `RoleId`.

The code below shows my latest attempt at gathering all the data together into a single DTO object, with one exception - I can't seem to load the `Roles` associated with the `RoleId`(s) that appear in the `UserRoles` collection.

Any suggestions on how I can load the associated Role collection? I'm going have to iterate through the Role collection to add the friendly name of the role to the user claims, and right now, I'm just ending up with a big fat null.

```
var validatedUser = _context.User
                .Where(x => string.Equals(x.UserName, username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Active)
                .Include(x => x.UserRole)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
                .Select(result => new ValidatedUser
                {
                    Id = result.Id,
                    Email = result.Email,
                    FirstName = result.FirstName,
                    LastName = result.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = result.PhoneNumber,
                    Username = result.UserName,
                    UserRoles = result.UserRole,
                    //Roles = result.Role, // this is where failure happens
                    PasswordHash = result.PasswordHash
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit 1 - showing the modelBuilder for the UserRole**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
    entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("UserID");
    entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleID");
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
        .WithMany(p => p.UserRole)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_UserRole_RoleID");
     entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
        .WithMany(p => p.UserRole)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_UserRole_UserID");
});
```

Here's the ValidatedUser class:

```
public class ValidatedUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FormattedPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber)) return PhoneNumber;

            switch (PhoneNumber.Length)
            {
                case 10:
                    return $"({PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3)}) {PhoneNumber.Substring(3, 3)}-{PhoneNumber.Substring(6, 4)}";
                default:
                    return PhoneNumber;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: check for `result.UserRole.FirstOrDefault().Role`

Comment: @Bharat, I'm not quite sure how that would help me in this scenario. I want all the roles associated with the user to be included in the returned object, not just a single role. That's why I was thinking that the `.ThenInclude` would be appropriate.

Comment: ok in that case, what if you don't convert your data to ValidatedUser, and just see what are you getting in your var validatedUser

Comment: This is just a guess (I can't test right now) but try changing the var name in ThenInclude to .ThenInclude(userRole => userRole.Role)

Comment: @Sopuli unfortunately, that was not the magic bullet. I was unable to get any awareness of the `userRole` once it came to selecting into the `ValidatedUser` object that will be returned.

Comment: @Sopuli .ThenInclude(userRole => userRole.Role) is equivalent to (x=>x.Role)

Comment: @Sumitraj Re-using the same var names in composite linq query can cause trouble in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the Include & ThenInclude statements are unnecessary since you're doing a select statement that will be evaluated server side.

For the query, what about this:

```
var validatedUser = 
    _context.User
    .Where(x => string.Equals(x.UserName, username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Active)
    .Select(result => new ValidatedUser
    {
        Id = result.Id,
        Email = result.Email,
        FirstName = result.FirstName,
        LastName = result.LastName,
        PhoneNumber = result.PhoneNumber,
        Username = result.UserName,
        Roles = result.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role),
        PasswordHash = result.PasswordHash
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If this doesn't work, you could always map the roles client side (in this case you do need the Include/thenInclude():

```
var validatedUser = 
    _context.User
    .Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
    .Where(x => string.Equals(x.UserName, username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Active)
    .ToList() // Force execution of query here...
    .Select(result => new ValidatedUser // From here on it's client side
    {
        Id = result.Id,
        Email = result.Email,
        FirstName = result.FirstName,
        LastName = result.LastName,
        PhoneNumber = result.PhoneNumber,
        Username = result.UserName,
        UserRoles = result.UserRoles.ToList(),
        Roles = result.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role).ToList(),
        PasswordHash = result.PasswordHash
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was able to use your first example, which I like because of its cleanliness. The only change I needed to make was adding a `.ToList()` onto the end of the line `Roles = result.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ,
Last day i answered a similar  question. It might help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51230593/8092001

This is not a correct approach to proceed since you already have foreign key referenced the table but still it will led you to ur result.

```
var validatedUser = (from user in _context.User.Where(x => string.Equals(x.UserName, username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Active)
                     join userRole in _context.UserRole
                     on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
                     join role in _context.Roles
                     on userRole.RoleId equals role.RoleId
                     select new {user,userRole,role})
                .Select(result => new ValidatedUser
                {
                    Id = result.user.Id,
                    Email = result.user.Email,
                    FirstName = result.user.FirstName,
                    LastName = result.user.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = result.user.PhoneNumber,
                    Username = result.user.UserName,
                    UserRoles = result.UserRole.ToList(),//I guess you don't need this
                    Roles = result.Role.ToList(), 
                    PasswordHash = result.PasswordHash
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I took a look at your suggestion, and, unfortunately, it didn't provide much help. The `modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>` has foreign keys to both `Role` and `User` already defined.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your classes ?

Comment: See Edit 1 posted above showing the class structure in the context as well as the ValidatedUser dto.

Comment: what is the difference between `UserRoles`  and   `Roles` for a user !!  are you sure `Role` is user property. My guess it should be `userRole` property.

Comment: right now, the `UserRoles` represents the raw join table in the database. Ultimately, I just want to be able to use `Roles`. And, maybe if I'm really lucky, I can even hack `Roles` down to a string collection/array containing just the `RoleName`.